# Integration test is failed expectedly in traivs CI, but ran successfully in local

Tags: travis-ci

My integration test would spin up serveral processes. And I can run the integration test sucessuffly in local, but when I move it to travis, the integration test would fail. The following is the error message I see. I don't find any userful info, it seems not caused by my integration test, but caused by the external world (maybe enviroment issue). I also ran the travis successfully in local by using the instruction here.  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Troubleshooting-Locally-in-a-Docker-Image

Error I see

```
 INFO [2016-12-06 14:36:02,147] ({main} LivyInterpreterIT.java[onUpdate]:303) - onUpdate:
DEBUG [2016-12-06 14:36:02,148] ({main} LivyHelper.java[executeHTTP]:346) - Call rest api in http://testing-docker-ca2e7f34-da95-4627-bc72-7e92273f5758:8998/sessions/0/statements, method: POST, jsonData: {"code": "sqlContext.sql(\"show tables\").show(100)"}
DEBUG [2016-12-06 14:36:03,274] ({main} LivyHelper.java[executeHTTP]:346) - Call rest api in http://testing-docker-ca2e7f34-da95-4627-bc72-7e92273f5758:8998/sessions/0/statements/4, method: GET, jsonData: null
DEBUG [2016-12-06 14:36:03,392] ({main} LivyHelper.java[getStatusById]:323) - statement 4 response: {"id":4,"state":"running","output":null}
DEBUG [2016-12-06 14:36:04,392] ({main} LivyHelper.java[executeHTTP]:346) - Call rest api in http://testing-docker-ca2e7f34-da95-4627-bc72-7e92273f5758:8998/sessions/0/statements/4, method: GET, jsonData: null
DEBUG [2016-12-06 14:36:04,528] ({main} LivyHelper.java[getStatusById]:323) - statement 4 response: {"id":4,"state":"running","output":null}
DEBUG [2016-12-06 14:36:05,529] ({main} LivyHelper.java[executeHTTP]:346) - Call rest api in http://testing-docker-ca2e7f34-da95-4627-bc72-7e92273f5758:8998/sessions/0/statements/4, method: GET, jsonData: null
/home/travis/build.sh: line 57:  6800 Killed                  mvn $TEST_FLAG $PROFILE -B $TEST_PROJECTS


The command "mvn $TEST_FLAG $PROFILE -B $TEST_PROJECTS" exited with 137.
store build cache

change detected (content changed, file is created, or file is deleted):
/home/travis/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.9.3-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties
/home/travis/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/resolver-status.properties


changes detected, packing new archive
```

Answer (score 1):

Error 137 means killed hard by the outside world (a `kill 9`). Generally that means running out of memory.

Apart from fixing the memopry situation, if your tests run with `sudo: false`, you can try `sudo: required`. You will have some more memory for your process.

Comment: Correct, it is memory issue.